# pythagorean triplet prints all numbers

Tags: python

I don't understand why but pythagorean_triplet code print all numbers, not just the 3 of it

```
import math

def pythagorean_triplet(n):
    if 1 <= n <= 90000:
        for b in range(n):
            for a in range(1, b):
                c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
                if c % 1 == 0:
                    print(a, b, int(c))



x = int(input())

pythagorean_triplet(x)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not just the there"?

Comment: Can't reproduce. It only prints the Pythagorean triplets for me. `pythagorean_triplet(20) -> 3 4 5,
6 8 10,
5 12 13,
9 12 15,
8 15 17,
12 16 20`

Comment: @BlayerBond I think possibly OP wants only the last three numbers to be printed, rather than the three at every iteration?

Comment: So ````pythagorean_triplet(20)```` should give ````12 16 20````?

Comment: @BlayerBond that's my best guess. shahrzadar can you confirm what you're asking for here?

Comment: In that case starting backwards would be more efficient, together with a ````return```` after the ````print()```` statement.

Comment: I mean like if it's 30 it should give: 5 12 13 right?

Comment: @BlayerBond just the 3 of the beginning of the loop. for 12 it should gave : 3 4 5. sorry I have bad internet couldn't answer fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I think I didn't understand the question that was given to me. the result was only 3 numbers. so I was confused!  and after I asked about it I found out that the Sum of 3 numbers should be equal to the input :

```
    import math

y = []
x = int(input())
if 1 <= x <= 90000:
    for b in range(x):
        for a in range(1, b):
            c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
            u = a + b + c
            if c > x:
                break
            elif c % 1 == 0:
                if u == x:
                    k = (a, b, int(c))
                    y.append(k)

if len(y) != 0:
    for a_tuple in y:  # iterates through each tuple
        for item in a_tuple:  # iterates through each tuple items
            print(item, end=" ")
else:
    print("Impossible")
```

Comment: Now it's even more confusing. What does this have to do whit Pythagorean triplets? I'm going to let you try to solve this on your own. Here's what you've gotta do. ````n```` = ````a```` + ````b```` + ````c````. For each ````a````, you look for each ````b````, for which you look for each ````c````, whether the three added together is ````sum````. Meaning: you shall have to write a triple nested ````for````-loop to iterate over each ````c```` of each ````b```` of each ````a````. If you still don't manage to get it working, let me know.

Comment: I'm confused as well. but as far as I get that's what the teacher asked. thank you, I'm still working on it. yes, I used the n = a+b+c , so far the answer looks okay but the result is a tuple (3,4,5). I will update my answer when I finished it.

Comment: When you want to post your answer, just edit this post, because otherwise this thread will become a mess. Goodluck!

Comment: so yeah I kinda got the result my teacher wanted :D thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. If you edit your own post with the solution and mark your own post as an answer, this thread can be closed ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of your question, but if the output should only be the last triplet, why not start backwards and end the loop you're in whenever you've found the number? The following code gave me: `12 16 20`

```
import math


def pythagorean_triplet(n):
    if 1 <= n <= 90000:
        for b in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
            for a in range(b - 1, 0, -1):
                c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
                if c % 1 == 0:
                    print(a, b, int(c))
                    return


x = int(input())

pythagorean_triplet(x)
```

Since you didn't return or break the loops, it will keep on iterating over the numbers.

EDIT 1:

If you only want the first triple, there is no point of using a `for`-loop. I suggest you test with an if-statement, whether the number is greater then a certain minimum. To be honest, I haven't really researched pythogerean triplets, but it's apparently - according to the code - 5. So the best way to solve this is:

```
def pythagorean_triplet(n):
    if n >= 5:
        print(3, 4, 5)

x = int(input())

pythagorean_triplet(x)
```

And here is what you requested, but I should NOT do it this way, because it's unnecessary complicated.

```
import math


def pythagorean_triplet(n):
    if 1 <= n <= 90000:
        for b in range(n):
            for a in range(1, b):
                c = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
                if c % 1 == 0:
                    print(a, b, int(c))
                    return


x = int(input())

pythagorean_triplet(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm just learning python, so every time I want to break the loop I must put the "return"? did I understand it right?

Comment: The ````return```` makes you leave a function. If this wasn't written in a function, I would have to write ````break```` twice, and keep a Boolean, to check whether the nested ````break```` has been hit. A ````break```` only breaks the loop it's in, so keep that in mind! Now, you've answered, I shall edit my post, for the code you're after. I advise you going trough simpler exercises first (there must be some online): start with exercises on ````if````-statements, then combine them with ````for````-loops and then start with functions (````def````).

Comment: Note that you'll always get the same result, since you always want the first to be printed, because this is the same as for 12, 20 and so on. Or I still didn't get your question :/

Comment: I'm sorry I just ask about the question that our teacher was given, he wanted that the sum of the 3 numbers be equal to the input. like if you enter 30 you will get : 5 12 13. Thank you so much, Now I understand the return function.

Comment: See my comment underneath your post ;) Or have you found a solution by now?